# random dots that obscure text in gnome shell when nouveau is used

Tags: gnome-shell, nouveau

I am using generic Ubuntu/20.04, using intel/nouveau as display driver

```
$ inxi -G
Graphics:  Device-1: Intel HD Graphics 530 driver: i915 v: kernel 
           Device-2: NVIDIA GM107M [GeForce GTX 960M] driver: nouveau v: kernel 
           Display: x11 server: X.Org 1.20.8 driver: intel,nouveau 
           resolution: 1920x1080~60Hz, 2560x1440~60Hz 
           OpenGL: renderer: NV117 v: 4.3 Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA

$ glxinfo | grep -i "OpenGL"
OpenGL vendor string: nouveau
OpenGL renderer string: NV117
OpenGL core profile version string: 4.3 (Core Profile) Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL core profile shading language version string: 4.30
OpenGL core profile context flags: (none)
OpenGL core profile profile mask: core profile
OpenGL core profile extensions:
OpenGL version string: 4.3 (Compatibility Profile) Mesa 20.1.7 - kisak-mesa PPA
OpenGL shading language version string: 4.30
...
```

It works fine for normal uses, except that there are random black/gray dots which obscure text when I activate action-corner (see below, I highlight the problem with yellow marker).

[image: random dots in gnome shell action corner when nouveau is used]

This problem doesn't exists when I merely using built-in Intel GPU.

Why is my gnome-shell doing this?  and is there a way to fix it while keep using the nouveau driver?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Well, the dots don't seem to be random, they are in the "a" and "n".

Comment: and small case "c."   font alias issue?

Comment: I'd say is a promissing clue.

Comment: I figured out now, thanks to the clue you hinted me.  I posted the answer just in case someone run into the problem as well.

Answer (score 2):

Figured out.

The issue is that I scaled my font using "Gnome Tweak" to 1.17.  Apparently,  the display doesn't like it when I scale my text to 1.17x of normal size.

I adjusted to 1.20 and everything fine now.